# Fixed cell size not working from css file

Tags: javafx

I have a TableView and trying to fix the cell height through CSS. The following works from java:

```
myTable.setFixedCellSize(80);
```

But if I comment that out and rely on the following CSS it doesn't work.

```
#viewtable .table-row-cell {
    -fx-text-background-color: #7f7f7f;
    -fx-fixed-cell-size: 80px;
}
```

The id is set to *viewtable*, I've already confirmed I'm targeting the proper element as the text color takes affect.  And using **-fx-cell-size** also works fine.

I'm launching this through eclipse and tried running from different environments from javase-1.8 up to 16. The javafx sdk is 17.0.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fixedCellSize` property is part of the `TableView` class, not the `TableRow` class. This:

> ```css
> #viewtable .table-row-cell {
>     -fx-text-background-color: #7f7f7f;
>     -fx-fixed-cell-size: 80px;
> }
> ```

Is applying the styles to any `TableRow` (at least by default) which is a descendent of the node with an ID of `#viewtable`.

Try the following:

```css
#viewtable {
    -fx-fixed-cell-size: 80px;
}

#viewtable .table-row-cell {
    -fx-text-background-color: #7f7f7f;
}
```